# Testing react-loadable components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-loadable, react-testing-library

I'm having trouble testing my `React` components that use `react-loadable`. Say, I have a `Button` component that, depending on whether it receives an `icon` prop, loads an `Icon` component like so:

**Button.js**

```
const LoadableIcon =  Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./Icon'),
  loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>
})

function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button 
      onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.icon &&
        <LoadableIcon name={props.icon} />}
      {props.children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

When I test this component, however, the `Icon` had not loaded yet, and instead the test only finds the `<div>Loading...</div>` element...

**Button.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-testing-library'

import Button from '../Button'


describe('Button', () => {
  it('renders icon correctly', () => {
    const {getByText} = render(
      <Button 
        icon='add' 
      />
    )
    expect(getByText('add')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Is there an elegant way to handle this situation without using actual `setTimeout`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer is to read the docs - **note to self**! The solution based on [docs](https://github.com/kentcdodds/dom-testing-library/blob/master/README.md#waitforelement) was the following:

```
describe('Button', () => {
  it('renders icon correctly', async () => {
    const {getByText} = render(
      <Button 
        icon='add' 
      />
    )
    const icon = await waitForElement(() => getByText('add'))
    expect(icon).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Also, note that `async` needs to be used together with `await`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have personal experience using react-loadable, but I have implemented a similar component that handles code splitting via the dynamic `import()` syntax.

To get Jest to work with 'loadable' / 'async' components, I had to configure my `.babel-rc` config for Jest to include the [dynamic-import-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) babel plugin that way the modules can be properly resolved even when the import is async.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm using `create-react-app` which doesn't expose `.babelrc` configuration, which is required to run the linked library, right?